With Microsoft 365 business account, shared folders are mounted but not personal folder
I am using Ubuntu 24.04. When I connect my corporate Microsoft 365 account with gnome online accounts, I authenticate myself through the navigator and my share shows in nautilus. When I click on it, I see the shared folders folder and a folder named 'root', but I cannot see my personal folder. What do I have to do to see both 'my files' and the shared folders?
